# How should I fix that after I use a slice of a tensor, tensorflow optimizer will break?

Tags: tensorflow

Here is a sample:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell


if __name__ == '__main__':

    embs = tf.Variable(np.random.random((40,5)),dtype=tf.float32)


    X = np.array(np.array(range(1,25)).reshape(4, 6))

    x0 = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])

    x1 = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embs, x0)



    lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(5,state_is_tuple=True)   


    outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm, x1, dtype=tf.float32,time_major = True)

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(outputs[:,-1,:])

    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=0.12).minimize(cost)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        result3, opt = sess.run([outputs, optimizer],{x0:X})
```

I use just one slice of outputs which is outputs[:,-1,:] to get a cost function. When I run the code, I got the result 
F ./tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h:581] Check failed: new_num_elements == NumElements() (0 vs. 20)

How to fix this? It's just a sample. I met this problem when I implement a hierarchical LSTM in which the representations of sentences computed by a LSTM is feed into another LSTM.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. However, when I try to run your code with TensorFlow 0.11, it does not raise the error that you mention in your question. Which version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: The version is 0.10.0.

Answer (score 3):

I confirmed that this is a bug in TensorFlow 0.10. [Upgrading to TensorFlow 0.11](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html) will fix the problem.